# Ignore jar signing in a web service?

Tags: web-services, jboss, jar-signing

We have some legacy JAR files from a vendor that were previously distributed as an applet, but we'd now like to simplify as a web service.

While the code works when I run it natively within my Eclipse IDE, it fails when I attempt to call it from a web service client after exporting it as a WAR and deploying it on JBoss (5.0.1).  The errors I'm getting are security related ("The jar file is not signed" and "WEB-INF/lib/****.jar is not signed by the specified signer.", depending on what modifications I make).  Is there anyway for me to tell my application server to ignore JAR signing for this project?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your jar has been signed (when it was distributed as an applet) and contains some garbage in META-INF. Remove *.SF, *.RSA, *.DSA from META-INF to "unsign" the jar if not needed.

Comment: I've tried removing the files from the META-INF, but when I do so I get a "Self-Integrity Check FAILED: java.lang.SecurityException: The jar file is not signed" error.

Comment: What happens if you also delete the signing checksums from the manifest file (i.e. each "Name" and "SHA1-Digest" fields from META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand why you would have to sign this jar. What it this jar doing exactly? Does it contain code doing some kind of voodoo classloader magic?